# Raphael translate function to transform function

Tags: javascript, raphael

Suppose I have the following code:

```
node.shape.translate(tx, ty);
```

Now, this line of code behaves weridly, probably because in the Raphael documentation, about the [translate function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.translate) it says:

> Deprecated! Use Element.transform instead. Adds translation by given
>   amount to the list of transformations of the element.

Now, what I want to do is to "translate" the code above into the Raphael [transform function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform). I am not very familiar with these kinds of details, so I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you just need:

```
node.shape.transform("t" + [tx, ty]);
```

which takes advantage that the string concatenation causes implicit conversion of the array `[tx, ty]` to a string using `.toString()` which just gives you the array as a comma separated list.

It seems pretty bizarre for them to deprecate a clean API call in favour of this string based format, though...

Comment: I believe the reason for the deprecation in favor of a string based approach was to allow more flexibility (i.e., the "...t(cx),(cy)" append translation and "t(cx,cy)..." prepend translation techniques, with similar functionality for rotation and scaling).  Still, much less usable in simple cases...